# How to build Portable Libraries on Team Foundation Build 11 Beta?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

we recently began to use Team Foundation Build Server 11 Beta with a build agent on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system without having Visual Studio installed on this system. Everything works fine.

When including new Visual Studio 11 Beta Portable Libraries in our solution, problems started. 
MSBuild was not able to find included 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.0\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets
on the build agent system.

We copied the missing files from a second system but now we get a build error
".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile47" not found.

How to build Portable Library on Team Foundation Build 11?

Best regards,
Björn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

> To install the Portable Class Library Tools on a build machine without
>   installing Visual Studio 2010, save the download file
>   (PortableLibraryTools.exe) on your computer, and run the installation
>   program from a Command Prompt window. Include the /buildmachine switch
>   on the command line.